# error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist

Tags: java, servlets, compiler-errors, tomcat7

I am trying to create my first servlet and I am getting the error above when I try to compile my code. I have read on stackoverflow that this is due to SE JDK not containing the servlet api. However, I am compiling from the command line with the following:

```
javac -classpath C:/Tomcat7/lib/servlet-api.jar; 
      -d ../classes com/example/web/BeerSelect.java.
```

As you can see I am making reference to the servlet-api on the command line. Please can you advise why I am still getting this error. I am using tomcat 7

thanks

---

**Solution**

For anyone that is interested..I located my problem. It was  problem with the Windows command shell and the fact that I had spaces in the directory names. I had the tomcat app saved as "tomcat 7" with a space. I was trying to reach it with "tomcat7" - that is no spaces.. The following line works

```
javac -classpath .;C:/Tomcat7/lib/servlet-api.jar;
      -d ../classes com/example/web/BeerSelect.java
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Maven, you should add the `servlet-api 2.5` dependency with the `provided` scope (see [here](http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2013/03/package-javaxservlethttp-does-not-exist.html) for more details).

Answer (score 1):

Change the forward slashes to back slashes, remove the trailing semicolon after the JAR, and try again:

```
javac -classpath C:\Tomcat7\lib\servlet-api.jar -d ..\classes com\example\web\BeerSelect.java
```

Also double-check all the paths, especially servlet-api.jar.

Comment: I see on some sites that they mention that there needs to be a ".;" placed before the classpath for windows systems..Is there any other issues I am missing?

Comment: That's a good idea if you have other classes in the local directory that are needed on the classpath.  It also looks like you're placing your compiled classes in ..\classes -- I assume that's intentional.